# "scalar-valued" Mathematica maximization error

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maximize

I am doing maximization using mathematica for objective function "f"

```
Maximize[{f, x1 > 0, y1 > 0, (x2 - x1) < l, (x2 - x1) > 0, (y2 - y1) < b, (y2 - y1) > 0, \k<= 0.3}, {x1, x2, y1, y2, k}, Reals]
```

it give me "The objective function should be scalar-valued".
did any one face that problem ? what could be the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objective function (f) is product of 2 or more matrices multiplication process
for example:

```
A.B
```

where A is (1x4) matrix and B is (4x1) matrix.
Then the product ( objective function) should be just scalar value expression with unknown parameters to be maximized. The problem has arose because Mathematica considers the resultant of matrices product is another matrices even if it is just one digit ( it considered as (1x1) matrix). Then when I tried to maximize it, the process wasn't logic for the program since it is not possible to maximize a matrix. So, it gave me that error

```
 "The objective function should be scalar-valued"
```

to solve it, first redefine the objective function as follows :

```
F=f[[1,1]];
```

then maximize (F)